# How to open my Chrome Extension in new Tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

Hi I have found other similiar questions on stackoverflow but none of them solved the purpose.

I want my chrome extension/app to be opened in a full tab like how POSTMAN extension is opened.

My manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Sample App",
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "0.0.1",
 "app": {
 "background": {
  "scripts": ["main.js"]
  }
 },
 "icons": { "128": "icon.png" },
 "permissions" : ["tabs" ] 
  }
```

My main.js (alias for background.js)

```
 chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
 chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('index.html')}, function(tab) {
 alert("Hi");
 });

 });
```

index.html is the file i want to load on opening the new tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first time responding here on stackoverflow, please be gentle...

I discovered that it's much easier to add "launch" : { "local_path" : "index.html" } within the manifest.json file. See my sample manifest file below.

```
{
 "manifest_version" : 2,
 "name": "Hello World!",
 "description": "My first Chrome App.",
 "version": "0.1",
 "app": {
  "launch" : {
   "local_path" : "index.html"
  }
 },
 "icons": { "16": "icon.png" }
}
```

Keep in mind that this example is very basic, it has been stripped of some unnecessary information such as a background script but it should accomplish what you want.

http://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app.html

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched` is only for Chrome apps, not extensions. The code for your background page will automatically run when the Chrome browser starts, so you can start directly with `chrome.tabs.create(...)`.

Also, you need to include `index.html` and any resource included in your extension that the page will use in a [`web_accesible_resources`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html) section in your manifest.